# The Blacklist: Blocking Malicious domains using Bash

Tags: bash, linux, shell, sh

I've made this script to automate blocking some deviant hosts on my router, and was curious if there's anything much else that can be done to make it quicker and more efficient.

Presently I'm restricted to using packages available on the [Entware repository](https://bin.entware.net/armv7sf-k3.2/Packages.html) and the latest Busybox/ash shell environment. So, for example, I can't use commands like `sort -S 25% --parallel=4 -u adblock.sources` (though awk/gawk is faster and more memory efficient anyway).

**update_the_blacklist.sh**

```bsh
curl -GOs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/T145/packages/master/net/adblock/files/adblock.sources

for key in $(jq -r 'keys[]' adblock.sources); do
        case $key in
        gaming | osid_basic )
                # Ignore these lists
                ;;
        * )
                url=$(jq -r ".$key.url" adblock.sources)
                rule=$(jq -r ".$key.rule" adblock.sources)

                case $url in
                *.tar.gz )
                        curl -s $url | \
                        tar -xOzf - | \
                        gawk "$rule" | \
                        sed "s/\r//g" | \
                        sed 's/^/0.0.0.0 /' >> the_blacklist.temp.txt
                        ;;
                * )
                        curl -s $url | \
                        gawk "$rule" | \
                        sed "s/\r//g" | \
                        sed 's/^/0.0.0.0 /' >> the_blacklist.temp.txt
                esac

                unset url
                unset rule
        esac
done

# Filter duplicate hosts
gawk '!a[$0]++' the_blacklist.temp.txt > the_blacklist.txt

rm the_blacklist.temp.txt
rm adblock.sources
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're missing a shebang line.  The question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), but that seems overkill, since there's nothing here that's not standard POSIX shell.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

We append to `the_blacklist.temp.txt`, but don't ensure that it starts off empty, or that it's even writeable.  It's best to create temporary files using `mktemp`:

```
tmpfile=mktemp || exit $?
trap "rm $tmpfile" EXIT
```

Also, instead of directing final output to `the_blacklist.txt`, it would be more flexible to write to standard output, and let the user choose where to send it (perhaps pipe into another filter).

But there seems to be no reason to use a file here - just pipe the `for` loop directly into `awk` (or into `sort -u` - that may be a better choice if you're memory-constrained, as it will perform an external merge-sort if it needs to).

The duplicated `sed` pipe could be replaced with a single `sed` program of two commands:

```
for
    …
done |
    sed -e 's/\r//g' -e 's/^/0.0.0.0 /' | gawk '!a[$0]++'
```

There's a security issue here:

> ```
>                     gawk "$rule" | \
> ```

We are executing downloaded content in `awk`.  Because we can't be sure that the `adblock.sources` URL cannot be replaced with a more harmful version, we should run `awk` in its constrained "sandbox" mode, and use the `--` separator so we don't interpret the script as arguments.

```
                    gawk --sandbox -- "$rule" | \
```

---

These changes give me

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

sources=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm "$sources"' EXIT

curl -s -o "$sources" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/T145/packages/master/net/adblock/files/adblock.sources

for key in $(jq -r 'keys[]' "$sources")
do
    case $key in
        gaming | osid_basic )
        # Ignore these lists
        ;;
        * )
            url=$(jq -r ".$key.url" "$sources")
            rule=$(jq -r ".$key.rule" "$sources")

            curl -s "$url" |
                case $url in
                    *.tar.gz) tar -xOzf - ;;
                    *) cat ;;
                esac |
                gawk --sandbox -- "$rule"
    esac
done |
    sed -e 's/\r//g' -e 's/^/0.0.0.0 /' | sort -u
```

Somebody more expert with `jq` could probably avoid the remaining temporary file by making a single pass over the retrieved data.