# The Blacklist - follow-up

Tags: linux, shell, sh, jq

> Follow-up from [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/261165/the-blacklist-blocking-malicious-domains-using-bash) using @Toby Speight's answer:

The primary concern is `jq` improvement/optimization, but please detail any others.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

sources=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm "$sources"' EXIT

curl -s -o "$sources" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/T145/packages/master/net/adblock/files/adblock.sources

for key in $(jq -r 'keys[]' "$sources")
do
    case $key in
        gaming | oisd_basic )
        # Ignore these lists
        ;;
        * )
            url=$(jq -r ".$key.url" "$sources")
            rule=$(jq -r ".$key.rule" "$sources")

            curl -s "$url" |
                case $url in
                    *.tar.gz) tar -xOzf - ;;
                    *) cat ;;
                esac |
                gawk --sandbox -- "$rule"
    esac
done |
    sed -e 's/\r//g' -e 's/^/0.0.0.0 /' | sort -u > the_blacklist.txt
# use sort over gawk to merge sort multiple temp files instead of using up limited memory
```

Comment: Please refrain from modifying the code. After getting an answer you are not allowed to change your code anymore. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). See the section _What should I not do?_ on [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I'm aware; the only change was a minor typo. Nothing about how the overall program works has been altered, and the change doesn't affect the chosen answer at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `for` loop to iterate over program output. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Try this -- extract the keys, urls, rules all at once:

```sh
jq -r 'keys[] as $k | [$k, .[$k].url, .[$k].rule] | @tsv' "$sources" |
while IFS=$'\t' read key url rule; do 
    case $key in 
       ...
```

If, for some reason, your shell does not understand `$'\t'`, use

```sh
while IFS="$(printf '\t')" read ...
```